# Read column1 of csv file2 and match with column2 of file1, if text matches then add column1 value from file1 to file2

Tags: text-processing, csv, python3

file1.csv

```
9,hello-world.com.,A,192.168.0.9
1,hello1-world.com.,A,192.168.0.1
2,hello2-world.com.,A,192.168.0.2
3,hello3-world.com.,A,192.168.0.3
4,hello4-world.com.,A,192.168.0.4
5,hello5-world.com.,A,192.168.0.5
6,hello6-world.com.,A,192.168.0.6
7,hello7-world.com.,A,192.168.0.7
8,hello8-world.com.,A,192.168.0.8
```

file2.csv

```
hello4-world.com.,A,192.168.0.4
hello2-world.com.,A,192.168.0.2
hello7-world.com.,A,192.168.0.7
```

I have two csv files, file1 has lot of data and file2 has less, I need to find column1 of file2 in column2 file1, only the matches text should have first column value from file1 to file2 needs to added.

Output should have separate file or file2 get update with new values.

Expected output:

```
4,hello4-world.com.,A,192.168.0.4
2,hello2-world.com.,A,192.168.0.2
7,hello7-world.com.,A,192.168.0.7
```

Tried python code :

```
#! /usr/bin/python

t = {}
address = {}

for lines in open("file2.csv"):
    columns = lines.strip().split(",")
    name = columns[0]
    t[name] = columns[1]
    address[name] = columns[2]
    
for lines in open("file1.csv"):
    columns = lines.strip().split(",")
    name = columns[1]
    try:
        print("{},{},{},{}".format(columns[0], name, t[name], address[name]))
    except KeyError:
        print("{},{},{},{}".format(columns[0], name, columns[2], columns[3]))
```

above code tried but its copied all content of file1 as output but i need only matched content of file2.

thank you in advance.

Comment: Thanks, that helps! So, does this absolutely have to be done in Python? It seems a shame to write a whole python script for something this simple. Is it just the first step of a larger process, so you need the script, or is this a one-off task?

Comment: no its not necessary to be in python, shell script would be perfect. thanks

Comment: So, basically you want to print all lines of `file1` whose second column also appears in `file2`? Is the order relevant, if so, which one should be taken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data really are that simple (no commas within fields, no newlines within fields, nothing but the very straightforward example you show), then you really don't need a python script. You could do a simple awk one-liner instead:

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1]; next} $2 in a' file2.csv file1.csv 
2,hello2-world.com.,A,192.168.0.2
4,hello4-world.com.,A,192.168.0.4
7,hello7-world.com.,A,192.168.0.7
```

That simply reads through the first file (`NR==FNR` means "while the overall input line number is the same as the line number of the current file", so it means "while reading the first file"), saving its 1st field in the array `a` (`a[$1]`), and then in the second file, it will print any lines whose 2nd field can be found in the `a` array.

You could even do something like this:

```
$ grep -Ff <(cut -d, -f1 file2.csv) file1.csv 
2,hello2-world.com.,A,192.168.0.2
4,hello4-world.com.,A,192.168.0.4
7,hello7-world.com.,A,192.168.0.7
```

However, this will match the values of the first field of file2 no matter which field they are found in in file1.

---

**Important caveat**: csv files can be quite complex, so use this only if you have full control of your data and can guarantee that the conditions in the first sentence (no internal commas, no multiline fields) are always met.

Comment: it works but still need some improvement.
if the some of the content of file2 is not available in file1, but file3 have that contents.
Is there any way to check file2 content in both files file1 and fil2

If i am running in two separate commands 

awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1]; next} $2 in a' file2.csv file1.csv > test.csv 
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1]; next} $2 in a' file2.csv file3.csv > test.csv 

so the output file test.cv has only one command output but i need in one file.
thanks

Comment: @Sha please make sure that your question accurately describes your situation. We can only work with the examples you give us. So edit your question and give something that we can use that would also work for you.

Comment: @Sha [Chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) are strongly discouraged, please accept this answer to the question you asked and then ask a new question that covers your new requirements if you need help with that.